# Add a space at end of line if delimiter detected?

Tags: java

I have a method that I created to allow me to read in a text file and put individual words into their own element that were separated by `|`.

Example:

```
0 | john | smith | potato |
```

The above would turn into:

```
0
john
smith
potato
```

Is there a way for me to add a space ()  at the very end of the line if it detects a `|`? I want it done that way so I can achieve this:

```
0
john
smith
potato
<-- empty spot goes here -->
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static String[] read() throws IOException {
    String str = null;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        for (String token : str.split("\\|")) {
            list.add(token);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try with `split("\\|", -1)`, this will not trim the last cell (after the last "|")

Comment: @AxelH Ah. That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.split` as the strange habit to trim the leading empty cells, so if you have

```
potato||
```

The result will be

```
[potato]
```

But you can tell to not trim this with `split("\\|", -1)`. That will result in

```
[potato,,] //3 cells
```

Read the [doc of Split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) to know more. Here is the `limit` explanation :

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit **n is greater than zero** then the pattern will be applied **at most n - 1 times**, the array's **length will be no greater than n**, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. If **n is non-positive** then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and **the array can have any length**. If **n is zero** then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and **trailing empty strings will be discarded**.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `split()` method doesn't have any capability to consider another element if there is nothing after the last occurrence. Try this on [Java repl:](http://www.javarepl.com/term.html)

```
java> "a | b | ".split("\\|")
java.lang.String[] res1 = ["a ", " b ", " "]
java> "a | b |".split("\\|")
java.lang.String[] res2 = ["a ", " b "]
```

What you could do is manually add another element if the String ended in your character, e.g:

```
for (String token : str.split("\\|")) {
    list.add(token);
}
if (str.endsWith("|") {
    list.add("");
}
```

Comment: You should read the other answer or the comment under the question, they prove you wrong.

Comment: the `limit` parameter will tell you that you are wrong. I have highlighted the intersing part of it. So try this `"a | b |".split("\\|", -1)`